# Database Design - players for card based game

Tags: database-design

So i have been working on a little game after I learned how to combine php and sql. The game is a card based game. The programming for the game itself will probably go alright, but I was designing the database and found an issue.

I have 2 tables (there will be more, but these are the problem). One is called player and one is called game. player holds all the player data (i.e. username, password) and game is supposed to "connect" players to a specific game. The thing is that my idea involves having 10 fields called player01-player10 and all of them being foreign keys. There is a maximum of 10 players in the game.

I would like to know if there are any more efficient/better ways of doing this.

This picture shows what i have now. It is very messy (it looks messy).
[image: EER]

I have looked arround on the internet, but i don't really know what I should search for.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Yep.  Game Table attributes about the specific game, Game Players associates Players to game and has attributes about that relationship.  so Game has many players and players can be in many games; but maybe only one at a time.  So you resolve the many to many by an associative table GamePlayers.  you can even have a attribute on the game table to define the number of players allowed for a specific game. and an attribute on GamePlayers of "winner"  But this is all possibilities... without fulling understanding the game play involved, I can't say if this will meet all requirements.

Comment: didnt think of that. i think that might just do it, thanks a lot :)